# How to solve error 0x1 in Task Scheduler in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to run a task in my laptop, I'm using Windows 10 Home, I've created a task in Task Scheduler and I'm getting error 0x1 on the Last Run Result.
I've set the "Run whether user is logged on or not" and checked the "Run with highest privileges".
In the Actions tab, in Start in (optional) I've set the full path like this:

C:\data

What else can I try in order to fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: that error specifically means the account used by that task does not have the needed privs to access the path specified OR the task is unreachable/unavailable for some reason. _usually_ it is a privs problem. [*grin*]

Comment: I just did another test and in the Last Run Result I got the message “The operation completed successfully”, but the script didn’t achieve what it supposed to achieve

Comment: then you need to add some logging - perhaps just use the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet - to see what is going on. the `successful` just means the task ran with no error received ... it does not mean the _script_ ran correctly. [*grin*]

Comment: The account I’m using it’s the main account I use on my Windows laptop to do everything. In the User Accounts Control Panel it’s included in the Administrators Group

Comment: I ran into this too.  For whatever reason Windows 10 decided that the SYSTEM account was no longer authorized to run the script even though the week before it could.  I had to delete the task then create a new one, then it worked.  Frustrating.